# get absolute url based on requesting namespace

Tags: django, django-models, namespaces

I have a model in one of my apps. The model returns an absolute `url` based on the namespace i have specified e.g news as below.

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return 'news:detail', (), {'slug': self.slug}
```

whenever i want to get the url i just call `{{ article.get_absolute_url }}` and it works perfectly. my trouble comes when i try to access the `url` while on a different namespace e.g sports. The `url` redirects me to what i have specified in my get absolute url function. (Below is how i have named my namespaces).

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^news/', include('news.urls', namespace='news')),
url(r'^sports/', include('sports.urls', namespace='sports')),
```

]

My question is, how do i dynamically get absolute url of the current namespace?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by : "The url redirects me to what i have specified in my get absolute url function", url is a string and has nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: You can't do this in `get_absolute_url`, because you don't have access to the request object so can't find out the current namespace. You might be able to get it to work by using the url tag instead, e.g. `{% 'detail' article.slug %}`.

Comment: Note also that `permalink` is deprecated and will be removed in Django 2.1. It's easy to change the code to use `reverse` instead: `return reverse('news:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})`

Comment: i have changed permalink thanks.